# Getting error: Method 'Append' of object 'TableDefs' failed (-214741848)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Just upgraded to Windows 10 Pro and using Office 2016.. when I try to run a VBA script, that worked before on Office 2016 using Windows 7 Pro, I get a pop up box:

[image: Fix Connections Popup]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Connect_Click()

Dim strConnect As String
Dim DSNCombo As String

DSNCombo = [Forms]![frm DB Selection]![Combo2]
CboYear = Right(DSNCombo, 4)
strConnect = "ODBC;Driver={Pervasive ODBC Interface};ServerDSN=" & DSNCombo & ";ServerName=myserver;UID=myuid;PWD=mypassword"
On Error GoTo Err_FixConnections

'Dim dbCurrent As DAO.Database
'Dim tdfCurrent As DAO.TableDef

Set dbCurrent = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)


Set MyTbls = dbCurrent.OpenRecordset("tblTableNames")

NumRecs% = 0

MyTbls.MoveFirst
Do While Not MyTbls.EOF
    TblSource$ = MyTbls![SourceTableName]
    TblCreate$ = MyTbls![CreateTableDef]
    TblSelect% = MyTbls![Select]

    NumRecs% = NumRecs% + 1


    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, TblCreate$
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, TblCreate$ & CboYear

    If TblSelect% = True Then

        If CheckYear = True Then

            Set tdfCurrent = dbCurrent.CreateTableDef(TblCreate$ & CboYear)

        Else

            Set tdfCurrent = dbCurrent.CreateTableDef(TblCreate$)

        End If


        tdfCurrent.Connect = strConnect
        tdfCurrent.SourceTableName = TblSource$
        dbCurrent.TableDefs.Append tdfCurrent

    End If

    MyTbls.MoveNext

Loop
MyTbls.Close

End_FixConnections:
On Error Resume Next
Set tdfCurrent = Nothing
Set dbCurrent = Nothing

DoCmd.Beep
Exit Sub

Err_FixConnections:
Select Case Err.Number
    Case 7874  'Table Not Found
        Resume Next
    Case Else
        MsgBox Err.Description & " (" & Err.Number & ") encountered", _
        vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Fix Connections"
        Resume End_FixConnections
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out `On Error GoTo Err_FixConnections` and try debugging the error.  Are you using 64-bit Office, or 32-bit ?

Comment: Generally a good idea to scrub server names, usernames and passwords before posting code on the internet.

Comment: Using 64 bit office.. connecting to a PSQL v11 64 bit driver

Comment: Did all your references stay intact when you converted? None marked as "Missing"?

Comment: Can you tell me if replacing ` DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)` with `CurrentDB` makes any difference? Just thinking that maybe JET is not liking what it sees compared to the 64 bit Access UI. Longshot - but maybe worth a quick try?

Comment: replacing DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0) with CurrentDB did not make a difference.... I commented out the On Error command... I now get the following... Run-time error '7874' Microsoft Access can't find the object 'CIA'... when I click debug it highlights DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, TblCreate$... when I comment the two delete object commands.. it then says, Run-time error '02147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Append' of object 'TableDefs' failed... when I click debug it highlights dbCurrent.TableDefs.Append tdfCurrent... TableDefs is a column in a table it is looking at.